# having n states in react, assuming that n won't be received in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state, react-component

How could I have n states in a React component

Assuming that the component won't receive this n value in any props, is something that it will get from a database

Using useState will create the state, setState for each pair, but I need n pairs

Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript arrays doesn't have a fixed length.
You can do something like

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
```

And when you receive `n` values from database just set it to the array using `setArr(values)`

Now `arr` will be an array containing `n` elements retrieved from database. You can then iterate over it and render them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As T J pointed out. You can use an array in state.

Or, another option is to map n Components for each item, therefore instantiating n states.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...fetch data
    // setData(data);
  });

  if (data === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return data.map((data) => <Item data={data} />);
};

const Item = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.data);

  return <>Example</>;
};
```

Or if n is literally just a number, a count. Then you could do something like this.

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...fetch count
    // setCount(count);
  });

  if (count === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  const items = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    items.push(<Item />);
  }

  return items;
};

const Item = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  return <>Example</>;
};
```